# Deseo eliminar dinamicamente una fila en un formulario

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, codeigniter-3

Deseo eliminar dinamicamente una fila en un formulario creado en **Codeigniter**.

El problema es que me funciona eliminado un **div**, pero al intentar darle el formato necesario incluyo bootstrap entonces me elimina el div anterior y no el row completo.

```
<div id="mixes">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mix" name="mix[]">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cant" name="cant[]">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_mix" value="adicionar">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

y el script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var max_mix = 5;   //max 5 row

    var x = 0;
    $('#add_mix').click (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     //prevenir nuevos clicks
            if (x < max_mix) {
                    $('#mixes').append('<div class="row">\
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <input type="text" 
 class="form-control" id="mix" name="mix[]">\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <input type="text" 
  class="form-control" id="cant" name="cant[]">\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class="col-sm-1">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <a href="#" 
   class="del_mix btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                         </div>');
                    x++;
            }
    });
    // Remover el div anterior
    $('#mixes').on("click",".del_mix",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Poner el código en formato adecuado además de incluir la condición del IF podría ayudar a que alguien solvente tu pregunta.

Comment: De alguna forma puse el codigo de php y no me lo muestra

Comment: como pudiera decir aca  $(this).parent('div').remove(); que quiero eliminar el  <div class="row"> entero

Comment: @DelvisDíaz, ¿no le puedes agregar un `Id` al `<div class="row">` y lo eliminas por `Id`?

Comment: y como llamaria al id en el script???

Comment: le cree un id="row" o sea <div class="row" id="row"> y despues en el script le puse $('#row').remove(); ahora el problema es que no me borra la fila que intento eliminar, si no la primera fila adicionada...

Comment: necesito saber como le digo que borre específicamente el div#row al que pertenece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiqué un poco tu código y funcionó, el script de javascript quedó así:

```
    var max_mix = 5;   //max 5 row

    var x = 0;

    $(document).ready(function(){

$('#add_mix').click (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     //prevenir nuevos clicks
        if (x < max_mix) {
                $('#mixes').append('<div class="row">\
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">\
                                            <div class="form-group">\
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mix" name="mix[]">\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">\
                                            <div class="form-group">\
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cant" name="cant[]">\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                        <div class="col-sm-1">\
                                            <div class="form-group">\
                                                <a href="#" class="del_mix btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                     </div>');
                x++;
        }
});


    });

    // Remover el div anterior
$(document).on("click",".del_mix",function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove();
        x--;
});
```

Lo que hice fue sacar la variables y la función onclick del document ready para que los selectores de jquery pudieran detectar los elementos del DOM apropiadamente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 .form-group{
  background-color: #999;
 }
 .col-sm-1{
  background-color: #f00;
 }
 .row{
  background-color: #00f;
 }
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var max_mix = 5;   //max 5 row

     var x = 0;

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add_mix').click (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     //prevenir nuevos clicks
            if (x < max_mix) {
                    $('#mixes').append('<div class="row">\
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mix" name="mix[]">\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cant" name="cant[]">\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class="col-sm-1">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <a href="#" class="del_mix btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                         </div>');
                    x++;
            }
    });
    

  });

  // Remover el div anterior
    $(document).on("click",".del_mix",function(e) {
      
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove();
            x--;
    });
 

   

</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="mixes">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mix" name="mix[]">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cant" name="cant[]">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_mix" value="adicionar">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahora solo me elimina el  <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_mix" value="adicionar">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                </div>

Comment: probé lo que me sugirió dijo y no hace nada...

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta a ver si te sirve

Comment: aun nada...  si lo dejo como lo tengo elimina el div que contiene el boton, puse el ultimo que me sugirio y tampoco hace nada, es como si los parent concatenados no los reconociera...

Comment: Chécalo de nuevo, lo volví a modificar

Comment: Ahora si me funciona correctamente... Gracias por la ayuda... a partir de ahora tendré que dedicarle mas tiempo al javascript....